# JavaScript immediately closes after opening it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a Raspberry3 model B.
I've written a code that I want to launch on reboot.
If I launch the script in the bash it works perfectly. But when I try to start the script via doubleclick (execute in terminal) it opens the terminal for a very short duration and closes it immediatly after.
Same thing happens if I want to start this script at reboot.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var blynkLib = require('blynk-
library');
var sensorLib = require('node-dht-
sensor');

var AUTH = 'xxx';

// Setup Blynk
var blynk = new 
blynkLib.Blynk(AUTH);

// Setup sensor, exit if failed
var sensorType = 22; // 11 for DHT11, 22 for DHT22 and AM2302
var sensorPin  = 2;  // The GPIO pin number for sensor signal
if 
(!sensorLib.initialize(sensorType, 
sensorPin)) {
    console.warn('Failed to 
initialize sensor');
    process.exit(1);
}

// Automatically update sensor value every 2 seconds
setInterval(function() {
    var readout = sensorLib.read();
    blynk.virtualWrite(3, 
readout.temperature.toFixed(1));
    blynk.virtualWrite(4, 
readout.humidity.toFixed(1));

    console.log('Temperature:', 
readout.temperature.toFixed(1) + 
'C');
    console.log('Humidity:   ', 
readout.humidity.toFixed(1)    + 
'%');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You should at least post your code.. not talking even about further explanations.

Comment: double click will open in which terminal?

Comment: @Bharadwaj Bash

Comment: @GonrasKarols ive added the code by now...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is How can i pause my program :

using python : you should import os then os.system("pause"); :

```
import os;

os.system("pause");
```

Using nodejs : use one of the module from npm :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/system-sleep

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pause